# pagination when using listview in android

Tags: java, android, pagination, android-listview

Hi am developing an android application and i want to implement the pagination while displaying a list view into an activity.

I had seen many example related to this but none has solved my problem. That's why i posted this question here.

for implementing listview into the application i had developed a custom class which extending extends `ArrayAdapter<BoObject>` and am passing a `List < MyCustom Class >` into this like

```
new MyListAdapter(CurrentScreen.this, R.layout.show, customobjects);
```

For iteration I need to use the `customobjects` list am first getting , and i don't want to querying for server each time the more button gets clicked.

Can anyone please give a solution for my issue.?

Comment: if you dont wanna contact server each time more btn is clicked , how the new data would be loaded in your case?

Comment: Add an "status" View at the bottom of the main view, just after the list. Add some forward/back buttons, and when these are pushed, reload the list with the proper objects and update the page indicator (also in this status view).

Answer (score 0):

You can try the ViewPager (use it both on Gingerbread [needs to include the supportV4 package] or on ICS), this is used when you want to scroll from left to right by a gesture, even with this ViewPager you can directly snap to a page. On the other side, you can use a ViewSwitcher
too.

Both solutions lets you define a bunch of "Pages", with both View objects you can set the current page and so you can navigate forward or back to the previous page.

Comment: can you just provide me a link where i can get the sample for using the concept you noticed.

Comment: look here for viewpager example: http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/source/browse/

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution  :

get 100 items in each request from server , insert them to database (sqlite) and read from database every 10 item then display them in list (pagination 10) . 
when there is no more item in db send last item id to server and request for next 100 items from server . save them to db and do the routine again .

hope this helped .